# RSA algo in symbian c++

Tags: c++, symbian

i have implemented RSA algo in symbian using class

CRSAPublicKey and CRSAPKCS1v15Encryptor

wheter it is rightway to implent encryption

Comment: Can you be more specific? Why do you need encryption?

Answer (score 1):

With encryption, the devil is in the details.

There are many, many ways to get encryption incorrect. For example, with RSA, you need to use padding, or [a number of easy attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA#Padding_schemes) become possible. Even if you get the padding right (which, if you're using CRSAPKCS1v15Encryptor correctly, you might be), you have to defend against replay attacks, and find some way to get a trusted key. Or you might flub the comparison in the end [like Nintendo did](http://wiibrew.org/wiki/Signing_bug).

Rather than asking about how to do RSA, you need to consider the entire context of what you're trying to do. What are you using RSA for, and how are you using it?